# New to equipotent sets. How to do this proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that if (A-B)$\approx$(B-A)then B $\approx $A

**2.21 Theorem** If $f : A\mapsto B $is a bijective function, then $f^{-1}$ : B → A is a bijective function

Attempted Proof
I know there is bijective function.
Let $f:(A-B)\mapsto(B-A). $

Then by 2.21 $f^{-1}:(B-A)\mapsto(A-B)$ is a function.

Then ?
Help

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this venn diagram:

[image]

Your goal is to construct a function $f:A\to B$ which is a bijection. To do this, you can map the points in the overlap $A\cap B$ onto themselves.

Next the points in $A-B$ (the white part on the left) need to be mapped over to $B-A$ (the white part on the right)... but didn't you already assume there was a map (maybe called $g$) that can do this? Hope this helps.

Comment: I said f$^{-1} $ existed so ,that map exists. 
Ex let A={1,3,5,7...2n-1} B={3,4,5... n+2} Then $A\cap B$={3,5,7...2n+1} and f:A$\cap B \mapsto A\cap B$ is a bijection where f(n)=2n+1